# FFMPEG throws error while converting WEBM/MP4 audio files from MediaRecorder to MP3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4, webm

I use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to record the audio from the browser and then upload it to my server (ARM-based Linux machine - AWS Lambda Function, if it matters). Based on the browser type, I get either an MP4 file (for the Safari browser) OR a WEBM file (for every other browser) from the MediaRecorder. The audio is converted to Base64 string and posted to my server with FFMPEG.

**MediaRecorder implementation**

```
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
const MediaRecorder = window['MediaRecorder'];
const mimeType = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm') ? 'audio/webm' : 'audio/mp4';
const recordingFileExtension = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm') ? 'webm' : 'mp4';
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream, { mimeType });
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = convertBlobAndUploadChunk;
mediaRecorder.start(30 * 1000); // timeslice needs to be in ms
// When user stops recording
mediaRecorder.stop();
audioStream.getTracks().forEach( t => { t.stop(); });
// To convert the audio blob to string
function convertBlobToBase64(blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onload = () => {
            const tmpStr = reader.result.toString();
            resolve(tmpStr.substring(tmpStr.indexOf('base64,') + 7));
        };
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}
```

On my server, I convert the WEBM/MP4 file to an MP3 file for better cross-browser compatibility and to enable scrubbing.

**Backend Lambda Implementation**

```
const FFMpegCommand = require('fluent-ffmpeg'); // v2.1.2
new FFMpegCommand()
        .input(originalFile)
        .on('end', (error, stdOut, stdError) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
        .save(convertedFile);
```

This works perfectly fine 99.9% of the time but FFMPEG throws one of the following errors for 0.1% of the time:

**Error 1: Invalid data found when processing input**

*error reading header*

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the 
FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] could not find corresponding trex (id 1)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] could not find corresponding track id 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] trun track id unknown, no tfhd was found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] error reading header
/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

*EBML Header parding failed*

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x7595f40] Format matroska,webm detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[matroska,webm @ 0x7595f40] EBML header parsing failed
/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

*No specific details*

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**Error 2: Output file #0 does not contain any stream**

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
[mpegts @ 0x5d19f40] Format mpegts detected only with low score of 2, misdetection possible!
[mpegts @ 0x5d19f40] Could not detect TS packet size, defaulting to non-FEC/DVHS
Input #0, mpegts, from '/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.webm':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Output #0, mp3, to '/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.mp3':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Thanks for reading, any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.